# managed object context has changes - core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have an iOS application where the user can navigate through several different screens and input data.  These fields have their input stored in Core Data.  There are other screens that just display this data.

When the application connects to my back end to grab data, it then iterates through the managed objects and updates them as necessary.  After changing the values in the properties, I call save on a shared instance (singleton).

This is the code that causes the failure:

```
if ([self.managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
  abort();
}
```

I have tried researching this issue both here on Stack Overflow as well as on Google.  I guess I'm just not grasping the concept.  I'm using a singleton of a class to do the saves.  So what "context" is changing, and what should be done to fix it?  Please advise! :(

Edit:  Here's the dump in the console:

```
    "NSMergeConflict (0x16235580) for NSManagedObject (0x162a7bf0) with objectID   
'0x16460a10 <x-coredata://C5197C6E-6154-453D-84DC-BBD3F41B8D98/Comment/p69>' with 
oldVersion = 3 and newVersion = 4 and old object snapshot = {\n    comment = \"\";\n    
commentsOpen = 0;\n    createdOn = \"2013-12-13 23:21:05 +0000\";\n    imageURLList = \"
<null>\";\n    modifiedOn = \"2013-12-13 23:23:32 +0000\";\n "0x162b69b0 <x-
coredata://C5197C6E-6154-453D-84DC-BBD3F41B8D98/NewsArticle/p69>\";\n    snapshot = 
\"0x161698a0 <x-coredata://C5197C6E-6154-453D-84DC-BBD3F41B8D98/Snapshot/p6>\";\n    
snapshotID = \"a3120864-5b5d-4dff-8901-6fa84279700c\";\n} and new cached row = {\n    
comment = \"\";\n    commentsOpen = 0;\n    createdOn = \"2013-12-13 23:21:05 +0000\";\n    
imageURLList = \"<null>\";\n    modifiedOn = \"2013-12-13 23:23:32 +0000\";\n "0x162b6350 
<x-coredata://C5197C6E-6154-453D-84DC-BBD3F41B8D98/NewsArticle/p69>\";\n    snapshot = 
\"0x162715f0 <x-coredata://C5197C6E-6154-453D-84DC-BBD3F41B8D98/Snapshot/p6>\";\n    
snapshotID = \"a3120864-5b5d-4dff-8901-6fa84279700c\";\n}",
```

Comment: Why are you using that if statement with abort()? I don't know where is that piece of code in your class logic, but the if is true even if there are no changes in your context, so the app is terminated. Why you want to terminate the app if there are no changes to the context? Moreover, if the failure is during the save operation, there is the error object containing the reasons of the failure. Check it there an post more details

Comment: I can see in the console it tells me that it has two different versions of some objects.  My question is I don't understand why this is happening when I try to update existing objects and how it should be resolved.  Wouldn't the IF statement I posted only be true when it fails?  Look at the second part of the IF statement.

Comment: @LombaX: The abort() is only executed if the context has changes *and* saving the context failed, so that looks OK.

Comment: @Beebunny: Perhaps post the value of the error object.

Comment: You are right about the if, I've misread :-)  If you are saying that the if results true, it means that there are changes, but the save operation failed. The reason of this file is in the error object! Post the error description

Comment: I just edited my post above with the text from the console.  Please help =(

Comment: @MartinR: Can you please explain why exactly this error occurs?  I'm just doing an update on an object that's already in the database...